# Flot show false data in xaxis

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, flot

I use flot to show a graph on my website.

I use this code but I get an false xaxis. It shows:

Apr 4 12:00 Apr 5 0:00 Apr 5 12:00 Apr 6 0:00 Apr 6 12:00 Apr 7 0:00 Apr 7 12:00 Apr 8 0:00

But I want to have only (4.4.2013 5.4.2013 6.4.2013 7.4 8.4.2013). I want to have it without duplicates and without time.

Can you help me please. I search for several hours on google but I don't find a right solution.

```
<script>
$(function () {

    var     d1 = [],
            d2 = [];        

    var dt1 = [[1365041353000,3], [1365127753000,5], [1365214153000,9], [1365300553000,15], [1365386953000,2]], 
        dt2 = [[1365041353000,1], [1365127753000,2], [1365214153000,3], [1365300553000,5], [1365386953000,7]];

    for( var i = 0; i < d2.length; i++ ) {
        dt1.push([st + i * 3600000, parseFloat( (d1[i]).toFixed( 3 ) )]);
        dt2.push([st + i * 3600000, parseFloat( (d2[i]).toFixed( 3 ) )]);
    }

    var data = [{ 
        data: dt1,
        label: 'Test'       
     }, { 
        data: dt2, 
        label: 'Test1', 
        points: { show: false }, 
        lines: { lineWidth: 2, fill: false },   
     }];

    Charts.line ( '#line-chart', data, {yaxis: {
        },
  xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    timeformat: "%d.%m.%y"
  }
});

});
</script>
```

I tried this:

```
 xaxis: {
    mode: 'time',
    timeformat: '%d.%m.%y',
    tickFormatter: function (val, axis) {
        var d = new Date(val);
        d.getUTCDate() + "." + d.getUTCMonth() + "." + d.getUTCFullYear();
        }

  }
```

But I get the same
Apr 4 12:00Apr 5 0:00Apr 5 12:00Apr 6 0:00Apr 6 12:00Apr 7 0:00Apr 7 12:00Apr 8 0:00

---

I tried this:

```
 xaxis: {
    mode: 'time',
    timeformat: '%d.%m.%y',
    tickFormatter: function (val, axis) {
        var d = new Date(val);
        d.getUTCDate() + "." + d.getUTCMonth() + "." + d.getUTCFullYear();
        }

  }
```

But I get the same
Apr 4 12:00Apr 5 0:00Apr 5 12:00Apr 6 0:00Apr 6 12:00Apr 7 0:00Apr 7 12:00Apr 8 0:00

Comment: What version of Flot are you using?  Also, where does 'Charts.line' come from?  Normally Flot registers its main function as $.plot.

Comment: I use Javascript plotting library for jQuery, v. 0.7

Comment: You must be using something else, too, because Flot uses $.plot, not Charts.line.  Since it looks like your options are being ignored, it's important to understand where Charts.line is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tickFormatter on xaxis this way:

```
tickFormatter: function (val, axis) {
   var d = new Date(val);
   return d.getUTCDate() + "." + d.getUTCMonth() + "." + d.getUTCFullYear();
}
```

For duplicates, it depends on your app's logic on how you wish to handle it. You could create a map of what values you've already handled, and if you come across it again return null or blank value.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. How or where I must integrate it on my code?

Comment: I missed putting return. Change the second line to: `return d.getUTCDate() + "." + d.getUTCMonth() + "." + d.getUTCFullYear();`